# How to find the length using literal_eval python

Tags: python

I want to find the length of maximum obtained from

```
print (( max(sum(literal_eval(sub)) for sub in row)))
```

This gives me the max But how to get the length of max sum in python?

My input is

```
[0.0],"[0.0, 0.0]","[1.0, 1.0,1.0]","[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]","[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]","[0.0, 0.0]",[0.0]

[0.0],"[0.0, 0.0]","[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]","[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]","[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]","[1.0, 1.0]",[1.0]
```

First through max in find the max like in above example i got 
(4)
(2)
Now i want to find the length of max sum which is 4 in this case

Comment: `max()` returns an integer. Do you mean something like `len(str(your_max_value))`?

Comment: are you trying to return `3` from `some_three_digit_number_like_782`? Or are you trying to get the length of the `sub` that produces the highest sum?

Comment: @lanAuId `max` doesn't return int value. It returns `value` which can be even an object. For example `max([1], [2,3])` would return `[2,3]`

Comment: Yes i want this @IanAuld

Comment: What's the value of `row`?

Comment: So how i find out the length @ Tanveer Alam

Comment: I mentioned th input

Comment: Wrap it with function `len` should work for you.

Comment: I know you did, and it's unclear, that's why I asked.

Comment: Every line contains lists separated by comma i want to find the list with max sum and its length

Comment: I did it but it wont work @ Tanveer Alam

Comment: @abd: your "input" as shown looks more like a tuple whose first element is a list containing one float, and the rest of whose elements are strings, except for the last which is also a list of one float.  Presumably the strings are why you're using literal_eval, but that wouldn't explain the others.

Comment: But the above code gives me he max from these inputs @DSM 8. I only want to find the length of max sum How can i do this

Answer (score 2):

If you want the max length of your lists you can use a list comprehension with `literal_eval` to get a list of list then use `max` with `sum` as its key to get the list with max `sum` then use `len` to get the length :

```
>>> s=[0.0],"[0.0, 0.0]","[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]","[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]","[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]","[0.0, 0.0]",[0.0]
>>> len(max([ast.literal_eval(i) if isinstance(i,str) else i for i in s],key=sum))
4
```

Comment: this code gives me only the max length i want to find the of max sum of list @Kasra

Comment: @abd Sorry i cant understand can you explain more clearly what what you want?

Comment: @ Kasra The code i have in question gives me the max sum for lists like [0,0],[1,1],[1,0,0,0] gives me the max sum 2 I want to find the length of max which in this case is 2

Comment: @abd MY code will give you exactly what you are looking for!

Comment: @abd Welcome, if it works you can tell this to community by vote and accepting the answer!